# return array of struct with ABIEncoderV2

Tags: solidity

I have this error:

> UnimplementedFeatureError: Encoding type "struct Process.Process memory[] memory" not yet implemented.

when I try to return an array of Struct 
 I'm using:

> Truffle v5.0.10 (core: 5.0.10)
>   Solidity - 0.5.2 (solc-js)

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.7.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;



contract Process {
    struct Process {
        uint256[] tokens;
        bytes32 learning;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => Process[]) private processes;

    function _newProcess(uint256 _tokenId, uint256[] memory _tokens, bytes32 _learning) private {
        uint256 step = processes[_tokenId].length;
        Process memory process = Process({ tokens: _tokens, learning: _learning });

        processes[_tokenId].push(process);
        emit newProcessAdded(_tokenId, step, _tokens, _learning);
    }

    function getAllTokenProcess(uint256 _tokenId) public view returns (Process[] memory) {
        return processes[_tokenId];
    }

    function getTokenProcess(uint256 _tokenId, uint256 _step) public view returns (uint256[] memory, bytes32) {
        Process memory process = processes[_tokenId][_step];
        return (process.tokens, process.learning);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: why I have this error?